# Problema con un docker, no me ejecuta correctamente el código

Tags: docker

me llamo Luis y soy usuario recién aterrizado en el mundo Docker.  Tengo el problema que os detallo:

Estoy probando un paquete Python de pruebas de carga de web, locust, y para ello uso una imagen estándar que modifico con el siguiente dockerfile:

> FROM locustio/locust WORKDIR /home/locust ADD credenciales.csv
> credenciales.csv VOLUME /home/locust

creo la imagen correspondiente sin problema ninguno.  Sin embargo, cuando lanzo la imagen creada para el contenedor correspondiente:

> docker run -d -p 8089:8089 --name contenedor -v
> /path/desarrollo/local:/home/locust  milocust

Se lanza correctamente el contenedor y se queda a la espera, pruebo y funciona correctamente.  Hasta ahí todo bien.  Ahora, cambio algo en el código, guardo el cambio y al poner en marcha todo, ejecuta el script pero sin usar o acceder al script que ahora está cambiado.  Lógicamente, el script tiene el mismo nombre siempre (locustfile.py) y está almacenado en el directorio local.

Si quiero que se ejecute el script con los cambios, tengo que volver a reconstruir la imagen (docker build...) y no me parece muy sensato, cada vez que cambio el código; reconstruir.

¿Se os ocurre por qué pasa esto? ¿Se puede corregir?

Un saludo y espero vuestras noticias

Comment: Pero si detienes el contenedor antes de volverlo a correr?

Answer (score 0):

Estás construyendo una imagen para docker a través del builder,

Esto está hecho para construir una imagen y distribuirla en muchos servidores. Lo que debes hacer es ocupar la imagen normal y montar los valores de las carpetas locales hacia las carpetas internas del docker

Con volumes o -v

Carpeta local:Carpeta interna.

Una forma de entender docker es que tu código local se ejecuta a través de una máquina virtual entre comillas la cual ya tiene todas las dependencias necesarias para que el código se ejecute no hay que instalar absolutamente nada más.

Tú cuando tú haces un dockerfile y luego compila una "máquina virtual" que automáticamente contiene toda la información de tu proyecto lo normal para desarrollar es utilizar los volúmenes dónde mapear la carpeta local a la carpeta interna de tu docker.

Comment: Bueno, he revisado con "docker inspect contenedor" la configuración de la carpeta y me encuentro lo siguiente "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/path/desarrollo/local",
                "Destination": "/home/locust",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
Y en otro apartado anterior  "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/path/desarrollo/local:/home/locust"
            ], de esa forma te amplio información